# Media instagram endpoint not working - Invalid media id

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to use https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/, but for every media id that I use I get always the same result :

```
{
    "meta": {
        "error_type": "APINotFoundError",
        "code": 400,
        "error_message": "invalid media id"
    }
}
```

I'm getting the media id from another api service, for example:

https://api.instagram.com/oembed?url=http://instagr.am/p/fA9uwTtkSN/.

So in the response we can see ``"media_id":"558717847597368461_9538472"`, then I use that id in media endpoint and i get "invalid media id".

I was wondering if the api is having some problems or maybe I missing something.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess you are using a valid access token!

The app you are using, is it in Sandbox mode or live?
Instagram has recently changed the API endpoints. If your app is in Sandbox mode, only Sandbox user's media can be accessed.

If none of the above applies, contact Instagram! They can only help you.

Hope it helps!

Comment: The solution was to use my own data because I'm already a sandbox user. Still cannot use data from another sandbox user, but I now can keep on going with my app. Thanks.

Comment: I guess the other sandbox users haven't accepted your invitation or has exceeded the sandbox user limit. Somehow something is breaking which I can't debug from the info you provided!

PS: Instagram sandbox is not that complex, but it isn't that simple either!

Comment: @Sivecode_Santiago, just play around with Instagram sandbox features and you will just love it once you figure it out! I'll try and help with whatever I can!

Comment: The same is happening with me, i am getting it from sandbox user when getting public media with scope=public_content

Comment: they could have made error message more explicit :(

Comment: @Yerken, can't agree more! We have to follow what the Insta guys ask us to do!

Answer (score 3):

You are maybe getting that error because the user that posted the media is a **private user**. That was my case.

Comment: I have the users access_token saved. Still I can't get their media ?? That makes no sense

Comment: We can't copy links of the private posts. :) Do your research.